# why is my html not lineing up(Same code, different results)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

To start this off this isn't a repost its a different question, same code.

So last question I got the `h1` and `h1:small` to line up, i use that code in more than one spot and it breaks, (they don't line up). Am I doing this wrong? 
(Using Twitter-Bootstrap)

Html code:

works:

```
                         <div class="span3">
                            <div class="packspace">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <div class="well-small">
                                    <div class="center">
                                        <img src="img/Redstone.png" />
                                    </div>
                                    <h3 class="centerbg">RedStone</h3>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <ul class="inline">
                                            <li><h1>8$ |</h1></li>
                                            <li><h1><small> 512mb</small></h1></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="centerbtn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Doesn't work:

```
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="packspace">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <div class="well-small">
                            <div class="center">
                                <img src="img/lazuli.png" />
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="centerbg">Lazuli</h3>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <ul class="inline">
                                    <li><h1>15$ |</h1></li>
                                    <li><h1><small> 1024mb</small></h1></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="centerbtn">
                            <button class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


</div>
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 small {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.packspace {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.center {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

(PS I am using bootstrap(By Twitter)).

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second item in the list (`<ul class="inline">`) is being placed on a second line is because there is not enough space inside the outermost div (`<div class="span3">`) to display both list items on the same line.

If you want both the items in the list to always be on the same line you could try the following

html - I replaced the list with a single h1

```
<div class="span3">
    <div class="packspace">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="well-small">
                <div class="center">
                    <img src="img/lazuli.png" />
                </div>
                <h3 class="centerbg">Lazuli</h3>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <h1 class="inline">8$ |<small> 1024mb</small></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="centerbtn">
                <button class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css - in addition to the css you already have

```
h1.inline {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

The problem with this approach is if the text is too long it will flow outside of the outermost div.